# append text in <footer> tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I'm a fresh developer, my question is that I want to append some text in the footer tag, my code is below

```
<script>
    var result_string = '<?php echo $result_string; ?>';
    var newpara = document.createElement("p");
    var add_footer = document.createTextNode(result_string);
    newpara.appendChild(add_footer);

    var getFooter = document.getElementsByTagName('footer').innerHTML;
    alert(getFooter);

    get_footer.innerHTML = "<p>" + result_string + "</p>";
    //  $("#getFooter").append(newpara);
</script>
```

I am not getting any change in the footer text, please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('footer').append("<p>"+"<?php echo $result_string; ?>"+"</p>");
});
</script>
```

Since the question is tagged jQuery... here goes...

Just using jQuery to do the trick. No pure javascript.

**Update:**

Last footer

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('footer:last').append("<p>"+"<?php echo $result_string; ?>"+"</p>");
});
</script>
```

Comment: thankyou very much this works perfectly , but there is a problem , i have multiple tags of footer on my website , is there a way by which i can use only the last footer.

Comment: thankyou so much  @Arcanyx , it is working perfectly. thankyou once again , i want to upvote your answer but i dont have required amount of reputation, i am sorry , but thankyou again. god bless.

Comment: Happy to be of help!! :)

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByTagname` return an array of matched elements.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('footer')[0].innerHTML;
```

Update the below code, **use `+=` to append**.

```
var getFooter = document.getElementsByTagName('footer')[0];
getFooter.innerHTML += "<p>" + result_string + "</p>";
```

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ygpgwhjq/1/)**

Alternatively using jQuery (include jQuery reference),

```
$(getFooter).append("<p>" + result_string + "</p>");
```

Or

```
$(getFooter).append($("<p/>",{ text : result_string}));
```

Comment: i tried both , but still nothing is showing and i viewed the value of document.getElementsByTagName('footer')[0] , it says [objectHTMLelement]

Comment: It will surely print `[objectHTMLelement]` . Because it is an html element object. Write `alert(getFooter.innerHTML);` to get the innerhtml. Check my demo

Comment: thank you this is also working , but can you tell me way by which i can only access and append in the last footer , there are multiple footer tags on my page. and i want to append only in last footer

Comment: @HassanKhalid Use :last.. `$('footer:last').append($("<p/>",{ text : result_string}));`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    var result_string = '<?php echo $result_string; ?>';
    var newpara = document.createElement("p");
    var add_footer = document.createTextNode(result_string);
    newpara.appendChild(add_footer);

    var getFooter = document.getElementsByTagName('footer');
    alert(getFooter);

    getFooter.innerHTML = "<p>" + result_string + "</p>";
    //  $("#getFooter").append(newpara);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

### **Append the content to the footer using it's id:**

```js
//$("#getFooter").append($('<p></p>').html('<?php echo $result_string; ?>')); // uncomment for your code
$("#getFooter").append($('<p></p>').html('My cool string...')); // no php for demo
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<footer id="someId"></footer>
```

### **Or by class:**

```js
//$(".getFooter").append($('<p></p>').html('<?php echo $result_string; ?>')); // uncomment for your code
$(".getFooter").append($('<p></p>').html('My cool string...')); // no php for demo
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<footer id="someId" class="getFooter"></footer>
```

### Or, target the footer tag itself:

```js
//$('footer').append($('<p></p>').html('<?php echo $result_string; ?>')); // uncomment for your code
$('footer:last').append($('<p></p>').html('My cool string...')); // no php for demo
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<footer id="someId1"></footer>
<footer id="someId2"></footer>
<footer id="someId3"></footer>
<footer id="someId4"></footer>
```

Comment: @Tushar yep, but I remember reading somewhere that in certain cases it can have unexpected results. It was when trying to add something specific. I cant remember anymore what it was but I always just type out both now just in case.

Comment: can you tell me how to get footer id through getelementby ??

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: i am working on a wordpress plugin so the footer id might be different in different themes.

Comment: Then can you use a class instead?

Comment: Or if you know for sure there will only be one footer element per page you can just do `$('footer').html()` see my edit above

Comment: @HassanKhalid Also, I dont use wordpress but have seen others struggle with getting jQuery to work if not set up properly. If you can't get jQuery code to work, try changing the  `$("#getFooter")` to `jQuery.("#getFooter")` see http://digwp.com/2011/09/using-instead-of-jquery-in-wordpress/ for an explaination

Comment: @DelightedD0d there are more then one footer , your answer is very useful and working too , but now my required text is showing on alot of pages because there are more than one footer tag. i want to access the last one , can you help me.

Comment: Sure, just change `$('footer')` to `$('footer:last')`

Comment: thank you so much @DelightedD0D for your help , its working perfectly fine. thank you , i am sorry that i cant upvote your answer , i dont have the required amount of reputation.